# Why Do I Need TBN Matrix in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl

I think i couldn't understand the TBN concept, they use it for bump mapping, normal mapping etc. But can't they just extract normals from a texel using modelview matrix ? I need an explanation for TBN matrix, which i really can't understand usage reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every point and vector you use is defined in some reference frame, but it can be converted from one to another.

The normals that you read from a texture map are in "tangent space". This is acually not compulsatory, for example you could as well have them defined in world space. But think about it, what happens with the normals if you rotate your model? Tangent space rotates with the model, which means the normals do, too (even if you deform/skin the mesh). Otherwise, you would need to supply different normals for every possible rotation.
That's why using tangent space is a *de facto* necessity (in any case, it's the choice).

Now, thing is, your light and your eye are probably not defined in tangent space but in world space. And so is for example the half-angle vector, etc.
You can only calculate with things in a meaningful way if they are all in the same coordinate system. The TBN allows you to convert from one to another.

The vertex normal alone is not sufficient (but the normal and either T or B would be, the other can be calculated using the cross product) as you can only define a *direction* with a single vector, but not the "screw". So, without at least one more vector, your normals are not defined, they could be rotated around your vertex normal in every possible way, with every direction being equally valid or invalid.

A similar situation arises when you need to fetch several texels (for example sampling height maps, not normal maps). You have an interpolated UV coordinate, certainly. So it is well-defined which texel to sample.
But now you want to also sample the other 3 texels in a 4x4 quad. Or maybe you want to do raymarching. In which direction will you sample the next texel? You *don't know*, because you could rotate the UV coordinate system around the normal any way you like. Every rotation is equally valid or invalid.
The TBN solves that, because N points upwards ("away from the texture image"), and T and B point in the same direction as U and V.

Comment: what if my eye and light are defined in eye space, not world ? will multiplying with TBN work ?

Comment: Yes (or rather, yes and no, it depends). You can convert tangent<->world and world<->eye (using MV) and backwards as you wish. It does not matter what something is in, as long as you convert _everything to be the same_ as soon as you do math with them. If everything is in the same coordinate system, you're good. Otherwise, it will look wrong.

Comment: That was only given as an example, it is unrelated to the TBN. Half-angle vector is something one uses in many lighting calculation models (origin: Blinn-Phong approximation), it is the vector at the half angle between the eye and the light source. You can think of it as a not-phyically-correct but plausible hack.